# Set default tablespace in JDBC URL for db2 on Z/OS?

Tags: jdbc, db2, mainframe, zos

Is it possible to force all create table statements to use a specific database.tablespace by passing a parameter to the JDBC URL? For example instead of manually specifying it as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Message (id INTEGER NOT NULL, created TIMESTAMP, message VARCHAR(255),PRIMARY KEY (id))     in DATABASE.TABLESPACE
```

I'd like to specify "database.tablespace" in the connection URL and execute

```
CREATE TABLE Message (id INTEGER NOT NULL, created TIMESTAMP, message VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

Answer (score 0):

DB2 lacks entirely the concept you require. It handles the first tablespace the user has access rights to as "the default":

```
IF table space IBMDEFAULTGROUP (over which the user
  has USE privilege) exists with sufficient page size
    THEN choose it
ELSE IF a table space (over which the user has USE privilege)
  exists with sufficient page size (see below when
  multiple table spaces qualify)
    THEN choose it
ELSE return an error (SQLSTATE 42727)
```

Thus the way to achieve what you require is to remove access privileges from all but one tablespace, ie.

```
-- repeat for all tablespaces
revoke use of tablespace myspace1 from public
revoke use of tablespace myspace1 from user/group xxx
-- and make sure the ones you really need have access rights
grant use of tablespace myspace1 to user creatoruser
```

Naturally this requires that you plan your actions well, but the approach works.